# TypeError: ModelSerializer.create() got an unexpected keyword argument 'image'

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

**models.py** file

```
class Product(models.Model):
    """
    This is The Product table contining all product items.
    """
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    brand = models.ForeignKey(to='brands.BrandProfile',
                              on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='brand_product')
    # brand=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    category = models.ForeignKey(
        to='products.Category', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    # sizes = ArrayField(
    #     models.CharField(max_length=10),
    # )
    # colors = ArrayField(
    #     models.CharField(max_length=56)
    # )

    is_available = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    market_price = models.IntegerField()
    selling_price = models.IntegerField()
    description = models.TextField()

    # stock_status , visibility_status
    # product won't delete if category deleted, we have to do it manually.

    visiblity = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:

        ordering = ('-created_at',)
        verbose_name = "Product"
        verbose_name_plural = "Products"

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.slug:
            self.slug = slugify(str(self.name.lower()) + str(uuid.uuid4()))

        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.title)

    @property
    def discount_percent(self):
        if self.selling_price:
            discount_percent = 100 - \
                (self.selling_price * 100) / self.market_price
            return int(discount_percent)
        return 0


class ProductImage(models.Model):
    """
    The Product Image Table
    """
    product = models.ForeignKey(
        Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='product_images')
    image = models.ImageField(
        upload_to=brand_product_image_file_path, blank=False, null=False)
    product_color = models.CharField(max_length=56)
    alt_text = models.CharField(max_length=24)
    is_featured = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Product Image"
        verbose_name_plural = "Product Images"

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.alt_text)
```

**serializers.py** file

```
class ProductImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # product=serializers.SerializerMethodField(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = ProductImage
        exclude = ('created_at', 'updated_at')
        read_only_fields = ['id', ]


class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    product_images = ProductImageSerializer(many=True)
    discount_percent = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    category = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
        queryset=Category.objects.all(),
        slug_field='slug')
    brand = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
        queryset=BrandProfile.objects.all(),
        slug_field='brand_username')

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = '__all__'

    def get_discount_percent(self, obj):
        return obj.discount_percent

    def create(self, validated_data):
        # print(validated_data)
        product_images = validated_data.pop('product_images', None)
        # print(f"product_images: {product_images}")

        product = Product.objects.create(**validated_data)
        
        # print(f"product: {product}")

        for item in product_images:
            item['product'] = product
            # print(product)
            print(item)
            for i in item:
                print(i)
            # print(ProductImageSerializer.create(self, **item))
            print(ProductImageSerializer.create(**item))
            ProductImageSerializer.create(ProductImageSerializer(), **item)

        return product

    # def create(self, validated_data):
    #     image_data = validated_data.pop('images', None)

    #     images = []
    #     for img in image_data:
    #         image = ProductImageSerializer.create(
    #             ProductImageSerializer(), validated_data=img)
    #         image.save()
    #         images.append(image)

    #     product = Product.objects.create(images=images, **validated_data)
    #     return product

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        product_images = validated_data.pop('product_images')
        print(product_images)
        instance.name = validated_data.get('name', instance.name)
        instance.title = validated_data.get('title', instance.title)
        instance.brand = validated_data.get('brand', instance.brand)
        instance.category = validated_data.get('category', instance.category)
        # instance.sizes = validated_data.get('sizes', instance.sizes)
        # instance.colors = validated_data.get('colors', instance.colors)
        instance.is_available = validated_data.get(
            'is_available', instance.is_available)
        instance.market_price = validated_data.get(
            'market_price', instance.market_price)
        instance.selling_price = validated_data.get(
            'selling_price', instance.selling_price)
        instance.description = validated_data.get(
            'description', instance.description)
        instance.visiblity = validated_data.get(
            'visiblity', instance.visiblity)
        instance.save()

        keep_images = []
        for image in product_images:
            if "id" in image.keys():
                if ProductImage.objects.filter(id=image["id"]).exists():
                    i = ProductImage.objects.get(id=image["id"])
                    i.image = image.get('image', i.image)
                    i.product_color = image.get(
                        'product_color', i.product_color)
                    i.alt_text = image.get('alt_text', i.alt_text)
                    i.is_featured = image.get('is_featured', i.is_featured)
                    i.save()
                    keep_images.append(i.id)
                else:
                    continue
            else:
                i = ProductImage.objects.create(**image, product=instance)
                keep_images.append(i.id)

        for image in instance.images:
            if image.id not in keep_images:
                image.delete()

        return instance
```

**views.py** file

```
class ProductModelViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
    parser_classes = [FormParser, MultiPartParser, JSONParser]
    http_method_names = ['get', 'post', 'put', 'delete', 'head', 'options']
    pagination_class = ProductPagination
    lookup_field = "slug"

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        # if self.action
        return super().get_serializer_class()

    def get_queryset(self):

        if self.request.user.is_authenticated and self.request.user.is_brand or self.request.user.is_staff:
            queryset = Product.objects.all()

        else:
            queryset = Product.objects.filter(visiblity=True)

        return queryset

    def get_permissions(self):

        if self.action == 'create':

            self.permission_classes = [
                IsAuthenticated, IsStaffOrIsBrandUser]

        elif self.action in ['update', 'destroy']:

            if self.request.user.is_authenticated and self.request.user.is_brand:
                self.permission_classes = [
                    IsAuthenticated, IsBrandUser, AccessOwnProduct]
            else:
                self.permission_classes = [
                    IsAuthenticated, IsAdminUser]

        else:

            self.permission_classes = [IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly]

        return super(ProductModelViewset, self).get_permissions()

    def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        return super().update(request, *args, **kwargs)

    @action(detail=True, methods=['GET'], name='Related Products')
    def related_products(self, request, slug):

        product_queryset = Product.objects.filter(visiblity=True)
        product = product_queryset.get(slug=slug)
        category_products = product_queryset.filter(
            category=product.category)
        category_products_s = self.serializer_class(
            category_products, many=True, context={'request': request})
        res_context = {
            "product": product.title,
            "category": product.category.title,
            "related_products": category_products_s.data
        }
        return Response(res_context, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

**url**

http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/products/products/ [POST] (authenticated and is_brand=True)

After givivg post request in this link, i am facing error, i have used here nested serializer.
[image: request from postman]
[image: reqeust from postman 2]
TypeError: ModelSerializer.create() got an unexpected keyword argument 'image'
**command prompt error**

```
Internal Server Error: /api/v1/products/products/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Django\merchbd\core-backend\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "D:\Django\merchbd\core-backend\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "D:\Django\merchbd\core-backend\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Django\merchbd\core-backend\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\viewsets.py", line 125, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Django\merchbd\core-backend\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "D:\Django\merchbd\core-backend\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "D:\Django\merchbd\core-backend\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "D:\Django\merchbd\core-backend\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 506, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Django\merchbd\core-backend\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\mixins.py", line 19, in create
    self.perform_create(serializer)
  File "D:\Django\merchbd\core-backend\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\mixins.py", line 24, in perform_create
    serializer.save()
  File "D:\Django\merchbd\core-backend\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 205, in save
    self.instance = self.create(validated_data)
  File "D:\Django\merchbd\core-backend\app\products\serializers.py", line 77, in create
    print(ProductImageSerializer.create(**item))
TypeError: ModelSerializer.create() got an unexpected keyword argument 'image'
```

***please help me , how to solve this problem?***

Comment: Could you share your `JSON API` data that send to the `post` request?

Comment: In ur `create()` method within the serializer try to print  `product_images`.

Comment: concerning your last edit, please read 
[**How should we treat posts that are vandalized by their original authors?**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/106812/251777)

Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on Stack Overflow, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the CC BY-SA 4.0 

license for Stack Overflow to distribute that content. By Stack Overflow policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 2):

Default serializer `create` method is:

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    return Model(**validated_data)
```

Let's say that your `item` is `{'image': 'image.jpg', 'name': 'cool image'}`

So

```
print(ProductImageSerializer.create(**item))
```

is the same as

```
print(ProductImageSerializer.create(image=item['image'], name=item['name']))
```

but correct code is

```
# instantiate class to be able parse self
serializer = ProductImageSerializer(data=item)
# check if data is correct
serializer.is_valid()
# run create method
print(serializer.create(validated_data=serializer.validated_data))
```

PS. and of course next line `ProductImageSerializer.create(ProductImageSerializer(), **item)` is not correct too

Comment: after doing that, it is showing ``` File "D:\Django\merchbd\core-backend\app\products\serializers.py", line 77, in create
    print(ProductImageSerializer.create(validated_data=item))
TypeError: ModelSerializer.create() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'```

Comment: print(ProductImageSerializer.create(validated_data=item))
TypeError: ModelSerializer.create() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Comment: @MinhazChowdhury Yes, sorry, my bad. You should instantiate class first (updated my answer)

Comment: now it is giving error, ``` return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: products_productimage.product_id```

Comment: what is output for `print(serializer.validated_data)`?

Comment: serializer.data: {'image': <InMemoryUploadedFile: 2022-01-18.png (image/png)>, 'product_color': 'red', 'alt_text': 'hello alt', 'is_featured': False, 'product': <Product: Product Fakku>}
serializer.is_valid: False
print(serializer.validated_data): {}

Comment: serializer.validated_data = {}: because serializer.is_valid()=False

Comment: @MinhazChowdhury `serializer.is_valid()=False` → Yep. You've got it! And now you must to check why it is not valid. Or simply use `serializer.data` instead of `serializer.validated_data` if validation is not matter. PS at first sight `serializer.data` is looking correct, so I don't understand where is current problem.